# JAR file running but no window/GUI showing

Tags: java, ubuntu, java-8, jar, gnome

I'm trying to run a simple JAR file. When I do so nothing seems to happen. (File is marked as executable and I gave it `777` rights)

If i do `ps ux` I can see the process is running, but I cannot see it's window/GUI.

This is the output of `update-java-alternatives -l`:

```
java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64       1081       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
```

[image]

(image of ps ux, as you can see the process is running but no gui/window is shown)

PS: It is an Ubuntu 19 server, a connection through xrdp with 32GB of ram and an Intel Xeon quad core 3.6Ghz)

Comment: Are you sure is a GUI application? Post the main class code.

Comment: How did you lauch the jar ? By double-clicking it ? Do you have any output if you launch it from command line ? While the jar is loaded and then executed by java, the executable flag is not required.

Comment: @Neywat I've tried several different ways, double clicking it, launching it through the cli, when I launch it in the cli I don't get any errors/output, however the process is running

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam I do not have acces to the main class, but I am sure it is a GUI application

Comment: P.S.  A JAR file doesn't need execute rights.

Comment: @StephenC "I am sure it is a GUI application"

Comment: @StephenC I also have a Windows server where te file boots fine, and yes I am aware of certain parameters but none of them are required to launch the application

Comment: Have you checked the appropriate system logs?

Comment: @NomadMaker I have tried to locate the openjdk 8 log files, but there are none, there is also no (error) output in the console

Comment: @StephenC thank you for the help; I have tested other jar files to (one I made myself, a small game, and it doesn't seem to work aswell). Currently i'm trying oracle instead of openjdk. Do you have any idea what might cause this behaviourr (with xrdp)?

Comment: Might it be this?  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1110971/xrdp-stopped-working-after-java-8-install